# Multiple symbols for various attributes of same feature

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point, symbology, fields-attributes

I have a point feature class where many points have more than one value for the same attribute (the values are in a single column in the attribute table, separated by commas). I am thinking of displaying such point features with multiple symbols side-by-side for each point, with each symbol representing a value of that attribute found at that point, a similar concept to what is done on [this map](https://www.nps.gov/joda/planyourvisit/images/June-2016-Regional-Map.jpg?maxwidth=1200&maxheight=1200&autorotate=false).

Is there a way to do something like this using ArcGIS 10.2 without manually arranging the symbols?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried going to Properties --> Symbology --> Categories
There you can set the field that you want to use for the symbology and it will collect like items together in a list. From there you can change the symbols as you see fit.

Comment: What I meant is that there may be several types of characteristics, all, some, or none of which may apply to any point in a point feature class. For example, a campground may have a shower, a contact station, power outlets, and cabins. If there were a point feature class of campgrounds, then, is there a way to show, for each point, symbols for whatever of these 4 amenities are present at that location?

Comment: @Borillar0821 Yes there is. You go to Properties --> Symbology --> Categories --> Unique values if the data is in one field.

If you have it against multiple columns then you can do Properties --> Symbology --> Categories --> Unique values, many fields the second option and that will allow you up to three different fields with information.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this the next time I need to display data of that type.